# jquery .change() event not firing on iPhone

Tags: jquery, mobile-webkit

I'm having issues getting a jquery .change() event to fire in an Iphone. Code is similar to the following:

```
var checkboxes = $('#someelement').find('input[type=checkbox]');

checkboxes.change(function() {

//never gets here on iPhone
alert('hello');
});

checkboxes.filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```

The list of checkboxes is generated dynamically before this step, written to the page with an .append() method.

This all works fine in desktop browsers and Android phones. Using JQuery version 1.6.4

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried a current jQuery version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `delegate`, which lets you attach events to current and future elements.

```
$("#someelement").delegate('input[type="checkbox"]', "change", function(){
  alert('hello');
});
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.5, all [attribute selectors need to be quoted](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) (ex. the "checkbox" in the second selector).

Comment: SHouldnt you change the order on the checkbox and the event? Edit: Nevermind, I thought it worked similar to on(). But obviously not :)

Comment: It seems that the problem is down something else, but this seems to be the correct way of doing things anyway.